# PHP подключение к базе данных

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных. Написал это:

```
<?php
    $connect = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=comments; charset=utf8", 'user', 'password');
?>
```

На странице выходит это:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\phpdb\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\phpdb\index.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'user', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\phpdb\index.php on line 2.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит что не смог найти драйвер PDO

Установите через: apt-get install php-mysql

Comment: А как установить? Через консоль или нужно в паку с архивом php лезть?

Comment: Через консоль разумеется

Comment: Вот попробовал:

Comment: C:\Users\Alex23432>apt-get install php-mysql
"apt-get" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.